# Numerical Procedure generating different outputs in Windows10 vs Debian GNU/Linux 10

Tags: c, linux, windows, numeric

I was playing arround with the Maehly Procedure to polish the roots of a polinomial and stumbled upon something interessing:
The exact samame code gave me two really different outputs depending on the machine it was compiled on.

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ITERATION 1000

double poly(double x){
    double coeff[9]={-61.688, 72.5235, 72.822, -108.519, -5.12949, 39.9139,-7.07373, -3.91823, 1.0};
    double result=coeff[0];
    double buffer;
    
    for(int i=1; i<9;i++){
        buffer=coeff[i];
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            buffer*=x;
        }
        result+=buffer;
    }
    return result;

}
double poly_der(double x){
    double coeff[8]={ 72.5235, 72.822, -108.519, -5.12949, 39.9139,-7.07373, -3.91823, 1.0};
    double result=coeff[0];
    double buffer;
    
    for(int i=1; i<8;i++){
        buffer=coeff[i]*(i+1);
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            buffer*=x;
        }
        result+=buffer;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    double roots[8]={0.9, -1.1, 1.4, 1.4, -2.0, -2.0, 2.2, 2.2};
    double factor;
    double pol_eval;
    //Implement Maehly-procedure

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_ITERATION;i++){ 
        for(int k=0;k<8;k++){
            factor=0;
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
                factor+=1/(roots[k]-roots[j]);
            }
            pol_eval=poly(roots[k]);
            roots[k]-=pol_eval/(poly_der(roots[k])-(pol_eval*factor));

        }
    }
   

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("\n%d: x:%0.16f poly:%e \n",i,roots[i],poly(roots[i]));
    }
}
```

**The Windows output (Windows10):**

```
0: x:1.0072928773885637 poly:-8.437695e-015 

1: x:-1.0004044550991309 poly:-2.375877e-014 

2: x:1.3770602924650244 poly:-3.552714e-015  

3: x:-2.5000428878301499 poly:0.000000e+000  

4: x:-1.7318124315476966 poly:-1.136868e-013

5: x:3.0001628929552053 poly:9.094947e-013

6: x:2.2341265341600458 poly:-2.273737e-013

7: x:3.0001628929552049 poly:0.000000e+000
```

**The Linux Output(Debian GNU/Linux 10):**

```
0: x:1.0072928773885637 poly:-8.437695e-15

1: x:-1.0004044550991309 poly:-2.375877e-14

2: x:1.3770602924650244 poly:-3.552714e-15

3: x:-2.5000428878301499 poly:0.000000e+00

4: x:-1.7318124315476959 poly:2.842171e-14

5: x:3.0001628929552093 poly:-1.818989e-12

6: x:2.2341265341600458 poly:-2.273737e-13

7: x:1.5318471775081237 poly:0.000000e+00
```

The x are the polished roots of the polinomial, start values are saved in the array `roots[8]`.

Can you help me explain this behavior and,most important, help me understand how to avoid something similar in the future?

Comment: I'm not following why you have one array with 9 elements that uses all 9, one array with 9 elements that only uses 8 and in main an array of 8. It would seem that you could & should simplify this a lot.

Comment: on the poly_der function it was a typo,should have been 8, has been edited. The code was not meant to be optimized, was written on the run ro clean some solutions, I am too really sure that can be optimized!

Comment: Maybe different floating point precision/implementation leading to slightly different results. Depending on the condition number of your functions/equations, this can produce different results.

Comment: Please report the result of `#include <float.h> printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);` on both machines.  Perhaps one  is using `long double` for some intermediate calculations and the other is not.  Also what _compilers_ and versions are used (more important that stating the OS)?  For example I get `4: x:-1.7318124315476959 poly:2.842171e-14` on Windows, but likely a different compiler than you used.

Comment: I get 2 on windows and  0 on linux for FLT_EVAL_METHOD, both machines compile with gcc(MinGw in windows) both 9.3.0

Comment: are you compiling windows 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I am compiling on a 64bit OS

Comment: @Indiano compiling on a 64bit OS doesn't mean a 64bit target. MS still defaults VS to 32bit

Comment: Target is x32,sorry I misunderstood the question

Comment: @Indiano that will produce different results just an FYI than if you target x64. This is because the windows ABI allows for x87 by default for x86-32 but not for x86-64. This can produce wildly different results due to the way x87 works and the rounding it can add. [EX with just clang and GCC producing output](https://godbolt.org/z/xP8oj864x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to 2 issue, why different? Which is better - or may a 3rd way?

OP [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379217/numerical-procedure-generating-different-outputs-in-windows10-vs-debian-gnu-linu/70379979#comment124409442_70379217) different `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` values of 2 and 0.  This implies the Windows version is using `long double` math for intermediate calculations and the Linux one is just using `double`.  Usually the `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2` is more correct.

```
#include <float.h>
printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

---

FP have a weakness in subtracting values *nearly* the same.  The cancelation of many common bits leads to the *slight* computational errors becoming more significant. Different compilations may have slightly different rounded  result for various reasons, although I'd _expect the same.   `poly()` does that with repeated calculations to find a power of `x` and then adding terms that cancel out.

On my system `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 0.

Fixing both `poly()` and `poly_dev()`

```
static const double coeff[9] = {-61.688, //
    72.5235, 72.822, -108.519, -5.12949, //
    39.9139, -7.07373, -3.91823, 1.0};

double poly(double x) {
  double result = 0.0;
  for (int i = 9; i-- > 0; ) {
    result = result * x + coeff[i];
  }
  return result;
}

double poly_der(double x) {
  double result = 0.0;
  for (int i = 9; i-- > 1; ) {
    result = result * x + coeff[i]*i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Results with only `double` math rival the weaker computational code using `long double` math.

```
printf("%d: x:% 0.16f poly:% e \n", i, roots[i], poly(roots[i]));
0: x: 1.0072928773885645 poly: 0.000000e+00 
1: x:-1.0004044550991309 poly:-7.105427e-15 
2: x: 1.3770602924650324 poly:-4.973799e-14 
3: x:-2.5000428878301495 poly:-6.394885e-13 
4: x:-1.7318124315476964 poly:-2.842171e-14 
5: x: 1.5318471775081377 poly: 0.000000e+00 
6: x: 2.2341265341600520 poly: 0.000000e+00 
7: x: 3.0001628929552009 poly:-2.771117e-13
```

Comment: Thaks for the answer, I have one last question:  The better result in my implementation was actually for FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0, which does not make to much intuitive sense on a first glance, that the rounding error is actualy lower with a shorter mantissa. Is there some principle behind or "just happened to be like this" in my problem?

Comment: @Indiano "The better result in my implementation was actually for FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0" --> How did you ascertain that was _better_.  I suspect that conclusion.

Comment: Because is giving 8 roots of an 8th grade polynomial, while FLT_EVAL:METHOD=2 is producing one duplicate.

Comment: The roots 7 and 5 are both 3.00016

Comment: @Indiano I see.  But that is a convergence issue and not only a precision one - which I though was the main issue.  "gave me two really different outputs" did not point that out.  The convergence issue is that the initial guesses `roots[8]` were to far away.   In general, getting a good initial root is a _hard_ problem.

Comment: @Indiano To solve _getting a good initial root_ takes a lot more code.  (Perhaps binary search) Otherwise use hardcoded `double roots[8] = {0.9, -1.1, 1.4, 1.5, -2.5, -1.7, 2.2, 3.0};`

Comment: @Indiano The usual polynomial solution approach is to find a root (or pair of roots which may be complex), factor them out and solve the reduced polynomial until a trivial quadratic or linear one.

Comment: @Indiano Lastly, solving interesting polynomials like `-(x^3 +x + 1)` based on different initial guesses lead to my [profile image](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica?tab=profile).

Comment: The task was given in an assigment(initial guesses were given to me), my implementation was per se faulty( Notice that I don´t polish roots one by one, I polish them "all toghether"). I will try to have a look at resuts for less iterations with the hope of finding at wich step the aproximation is generated that changes the convergece of the algorithm.  Thanks for the support and interesting insights!